# Horizontal notification bar not showing

Tags: php, wordpress, notifications

I am trying to add an horizontal scrolling notification bar on my home page using astra hooks but can't figure out why it is not working when adding some php code, while only HTML and css code properly show the horizontal notification bar. May somebody explain why. I am also using WP code snipet.

```
<?php

add_action('astra_entry_content_before','add_scroll_bar');
function add_scroll_bar(){
    $thenews = 'Good Morning';
?>
<div class="scroll-container">
    <?php echo'<div class="mouvement">'.$thenews.'</div>';?>
</div>
<style>
.scroll-container {
  background-color: #7FB3D5;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color:#FFFFFF;
}

.mouvement {
  text-align: right;

  /* animation properties */
  transform: translateX(100%);  
  animation: move 13s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-90%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(90%);
  }
}
</style>
    <?php
}
```

When using the same code with only HTML and CSS it is working properly. Later on needs to retrieve $thenews from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code, and it [worked for me](https://a.cl.ly/X6unYDwP). Please note, you need to add this code to your theme's functions.php file, not directly on the page.

You will also need an if( is_home() ) check to ensure this only runs on your Home page as you indicated.

Comment: Thks a lot Sam, the code was fine as you indicated it was a Logic set on plugin code snipet.